# XSS when some keywords are prevented on the server side

Tags: web-application, penetration-test, xss

When I scan website with burp suite pro, I encountered a XSS. This XSS is

```
   <a b=c>
```

When Burp suite test other payloads that contain keywords like `script`, `alert`, `onerror`, this parameters can't pass. For this reason burp suite report only `<a b=c>` parameter.

As you know this means `<a b=c>`

- `a` can be replace `img`
- `b` can be replace `onerror`
- `c` can be replace `alert`

But this parameters(`img` ,`onerror`, `alert`) prevented on the server side. For fix this XSS problem, input validation can be solution.

According to burp, this is XSS. Is it really dangerous XSS?  What problems might I encounter when I ignore this XSS ( `<a b=c>`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that there are a whole load of ways to get XSS in such a case:

```
<style src="http://ha.ckers.org/xss.css"/>
<a onclick=alert(1) style="position:absolute; display:block; z-index: 9999; top:0; left:0; width:10000px; height: 10000px"></a>
<div onmouseover='alert(1)'/>
<svg src=x onerror='eval("...")' />
```

Just to name a few off the top of my head.

The [XSS Filter Evasion Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet) should give you some idea of how many ways there are to attack such vulnerabilities. Even if you blacklist a thousand different strings, you'll probably never get them all. Even if you somehow manage to blacklist all *today's* supported tags and events, across all browsers, your filters will be out of date in a month.

You need to move to a whitelist-based solution, or implement a proper semantic XSS filter library. OWASP has some [good guidelines on preventing XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) which you should take a look at.

Answer (score 1):

Web browsers evolve constantly. It is possible (although very rare according to my experience) that you manage to create a blacklist that blocks every meaningful XSS attack today, but tomorrow a new browser feature may introduce new possibilities for the attacker. You can check out http://html5sec.org/#html5 to see how many weird just got introduced recently.

So my answer is that this is *most probably* an exploitable XSS (or it will become one eventually), so you should implement more robust defenses like output encoding.

Comment: You right.Output encoding can be helpful in this situation.